# Script Enterprise Architect, Adding parameters to methods in a class

Tags: vbscript, enterprise-architect

Is there a way to add parameters to methods in a class.

I have a class as Element in a package. I want to add attributes, methods and its parameters to a class. The attributes and methods could be easily added, as class provides API for that , the problem is the class as element do not provide any API to add parameters to a method.

```
dim class as EA.Element
dim newMethod2 as EA.Method
set newMethod2 = class.methods.AddNew(method.Name,method.type)
```

Comment: @Lankymart this is an exception. EA uses in fact VBScript, but it has does some preprocessing to interpret the `as EA.Method` statements. These are used only for the auto-complete feature in the EA script editor, but are stripped out before the scripts are actually executed.

Comment: Far enough, you live and learn. Never used Enterprise Architect personally.

Comment: Thanks @Geert.!! Good day to you and @Lenkymart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `EA.Method.Parameters` collection to add parameters to an operation. See the [documentation](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/method.html)
This works exactly like adding any other new thing to an EA.Collection

```
dim class as EA.Element
dim newMethod2 as EA.Method
set newMethod2 = class.methods.AddNew(method.Name,method.type)
newMethod2.Update
dim newParam as EA.Parameter
set newParam = newMethod2.Parameters.AddNew("paramName","")
newParam.Update
```